# How to skip suggestions when composer installing

Tags: composer-php

Locally when I run `composer install` it doesn't show anything about suggestions.  In our CI environment it provides a long list of suggestions I'd like to avoid.  I want to see the output of what's being loaded from cache and that kind of thing, just don't want to see this.  I've been through the docs and haven't been able to figure out how to hide this.

The suggestions are (among many others)...

```
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing pear-pear/PHP_Compat (Install PHP_Compat to get phpseclib working on PHP < 4.3.3.)
patchwork/utf8 suggests installing ext-intl (Use Intl for best performance)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
```

How can I hide this output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `composer install` on a project that has a `composer.lock` file, it just installs the versions locked in the composer.lock file and nothing. In other words, the required packages and versions are already resolved and it's just installing it.

When you run `composer install` on a project with no `composer.lock` file, Composer will resolve the required packages and their versions and will store it in the `composer.lock` file before installing them. In this case, the project was not set up and you get notified about other suggested packages.

In the second case, there is no way you can hide the suggested packages list from the output (at least, at the time of writing this answer). In the first case, nothing is new, so it isn't shown at all.

The solution will be to push your `composer.lock` file to the server, which is a good practice after all (you don't want your production server to have other versions of the dependencies than your dev environment, newer versions might broke your site).

Answer (score 15):

As of composer 1.6.3, there is a `--no-suggest` option that hides all suggestions when running [composer install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) or [composer update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u).

Answer (score 1):

Since `composer 1.6.3`, the `--no-suggest` doesn't show anything about suggestions. But in `composer 2`, this option is deprecated, it has no effect and will break in `composer 3` (see [this link](https://getcomposer.org/upgrade/UPGRADE-2.0.md) for more details).

Hope that will help in 2021!